# How to add a customer to Google my business using PHP

Tags: google-my-business-api

I have an application for an organisation so now they have many customers so which they will add in the application ,I created so now the requirement is that when they add the customer in the application it customer should get added in the google my business  automatically i need to write the code in php .

> I read something about google my business api but not getting the exact solution can any one help me out with a solution for this in php